# Does Facebook Realtime API with webhook works with Page comments and User Posts as well?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does facebook realtime api works when someone comments on a post or create a post on the page?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes!

Use feed you wil get comments, like and posts.

[Webhook for Facebook with Subscriptions](http://ukimiawz.github.io/facebook/2015/08/12/webhook-facebook-subscriptions/)

Comment: I am testing this. I get a callback for when I like, unlike and comment  on my own post. However when I share the post I'm not getting a callback.